# Moodle quiz answers images not visible in student Role

Tags: php

Images for the answers to Moodle quizzes are not available to students, yet they are visible on a non-editing teacher's tablet device. how resolve in this problem

Images of the answers to quizzes that I assign as non-editing teachers appear on tablets. But the student role is not apparent Answer to the quiz